# PHP Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream

Tags: php, apache

I edited the apache httpd.conf file recently for the mod_rewrite to work. I don't know if this problem originated from that or not, but i'm getting this problem from that day.
This is what I see on the frontend when I run the software -

> Server error The website encountered
>   an error while retrieving
>   http://localhost/prestashop/. It may
>   be down for maintenance or configured
>   incorrectly.

There is no specific file that triggers this. But I saw that usually small programs that consists of 4-5 php files, runs fine, but softwares with a lot of files(like PrestaShop) don't.
I checked the logs and this is what I found.

```
[Wed Mar 16 19:33:39 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Mar 16 19:33:39 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/yomig/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Mar 16 19:33:39 2011] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Mar 16 19:33:41 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Mar 16 19:33:41 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/yomig/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Is your website root: /var/www/html/yomig/ or /var/www/html/? It looks like you may have broken the webroot with your configuration changes. What includes are you specifying in index.php? Do they use a relative path or an absolute path?

Comment: My website root is `/var/www/html/yomig` ..  And no file is included in index.php.

Comment: @AbiusX a little more explanation please.

Comment: I think he's suggesting that the webserver may not have read access to the "index.php" file.

Comment: Hey, The folder is chmod 755 -R, but still no luck. :-/

Comment: Try this if you're still having trouble: `chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t the_dir_that_has_the_problem`

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Experienced the same error, for me it was caused because on my Mac I have changed the DocumentRoot to my users Sites directory.

To fix it, I ran the recursive command to ensure that the Apache service has read permissions.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Sites
```

Comment: @John +1 for your answer as it worked form me as well... However, I'm a bit confused as to why this should be 755... My host (live server) works fine with 644 and I always thought that adding the OS user to the web folder was the right way to go.

Comment: Its due to the way the owner/group are setup for this directory

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: `755` is totally excessive, and arguably unsafe: you don't want every directory to be world readable, and it is overkill to give execute permissions to every file. In terms of your exact error message, you just needed `chmod 644 /var/www/html/yomig/index.php`. See answer by @Dexter for proper/safe recursive commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918548

Answer (score 35):

If you are running Fedora, make sure SELinux is not interfering.You fix this with this command:

```
    sudo /sbin/restorecon -R /var/www/
```

More info here: [linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/](http://linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/)

Comment: Not a very helpful comment. Fix like `sudo /sbin/restorecon -R /var/www/`. More info here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-2-warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-814037/

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error and my problem was the file permissions were incorrect.

```
chmod 755 index.php
```

worked for me.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 6):

Here some guide how to fix it. Go to :

```
cd /var/www

sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R

sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
```

Change userneme with your username. I hope it help.

Answer (score 6):

It is a SELinux blocking issue, Linux prevented httpd access. Here is the solution：

```
# restorecon '/var/www/html/wiki/index.php'
# restorecon -R '/var/www/html/wiki/index.php'
# /sbin/restorecon '/var/www/html/wiki/index.php'
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem when insert wrong file address into `.htaccess`

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/user/wrong/address/config.php"
```

So if you use **auto_prepend_file** check your file path. It called from `.htaccess` so PHP can't determine error file and line.

Answer (score 4):

In my mind true way is:

```
# add READ permission to all directories and files under your DocumentRoot
sudo chmod +r /path/to/DocumentRoot/ -R

# add EXECUTE permission to all DIRECTORIES under your DocumentRoot
find /path/to/DocumentRoot/ -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Comment: shouldn't the user `www-data` get some rights too? I would give `chmod g+r /path/ -R` && `chown $USER:www-data /path/ -R`

Comment: @Dexter: `+X` (uppercase X) is a better way to just affect directories. But it may not be available in all flavors of `chmod`. So in essence `sudo chmod +rX /path/to/DocumentRoot/ -R` might do, depending on your `chmod`.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 4):

I just came across of this same problem and in my case it was caused by selinux. Disabling it solved the issue. And no, I don't need selinux on my workstation, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me today with **/home/user/public_html/index.php** and the solution was to do `chmod o+x /home/user` as this directory has to have the X as otherwise the apache server can't list files (i.e. do `ls`)

Comment: `x` provides traversal permission.
 `r` provides read permission (but not without `x`)

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

This also happens (and is particularly confounding) if you forgot that you created a Windows symlink to a different directory, and that other directory doesn't have appropriate permissions.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

Just quote for above answer of user1992554 
This one worked perfectly for me in Linux Mint, to get rid of Warning: failed to open stream: Permission denied

cd /var/www 
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R 
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora 25, it turned out to be an SE Linux issue, and the notification gave this solution which worked for me.

setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1

Answer (score 1):

In my case the group `_www` that apache uses was missing in the folder's access list, so first I had to add the missing group, like so:

```
sudo chown -R _www ~/path-to-folder
```

Change `_www` to whatever user or group that apache is running as.

Find out apache's user/group using `apachectl -S`

The output is huge, but look at the very end something like:

```
User: name="_www"
Group: name="_www"
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but I had the same problem. I installed VSFTPD on my Ubuntu Server VPS. I could upload files, but every file I uploaded didn't have execution permissions (all files had rights "600"). These posts explain explain exactly what you have to do to configure your VSFTPD to set default rights on your files:

- [Default File Permissions Apache /var/www/](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1381217)
- [vsFTPd default uploaded file permissions on Ubuntu not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/571289/vsftpd-default-uploaded-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Once, this happens to me as well. and when I googled the matter, I got to know that this happens when the permissions on the file is wrongfully set to 000 (which means that no one can read, write, or execute that file). Then I just changed my file permission privilege into Read & Write and it's worked for me.

To change file permission settings on mac: Right click on the particular file and click on Get info from dropdown menu and refer to the sharing and permissions panel and change privilege settings into Read & Write

More: http://www.itoctopus.com/warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in-unknown-on-line-0-error-in-joomla

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Check dos and unix file format. This problem is seen on linux platforms if dos file format is used. Use doc2unix command like below and then retry it should work
dos2unix *.php

This solution for below problem

```
Wed Nov 12 07:50:19 2014] [error] [client IP1] PHP Warning: Unknown: failed to
    open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Nov 12 07:50:19 2014] [error] [client IP1] PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed
    opening required '/var/www/html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:
    /usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder htdocs

```
cd htdocs
```

Execute

```
chmod -R 755 sites
```

No need to sudo !

Answer (score 0):

Except the permissions, the problem can be open_basedir. If you are using it (and I suggest to use it) then check the settings at the VirtualHost :

```
 php_admin_value open_basedir <YOUR ROOT>
```