# PHP: Resource Temporarily Unavailable for simple "hello world"

Tags: php

I've just installed PHP.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.7 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 20:55:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I created a new directory called `test/` with one file called `test.php` containing this:

```
<?php echo "hello world";
```

When I start a php server and try to load it in the browser, I get a "Resource temporarily unavailable" error:

```
johnny at arch in ~/Projects/test
$ php -S localhost:8080 .
PHP 5.5.7 Development Server started at Sun Jan  5 22:34:01 2014
Listening on http://localhost:8080
Document root is /home/johnny/Projects/test
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Sun Jan  5 22:34:18 2014] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jan  5 22:34:18 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '.' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jan  5 22:34:19 2014] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jan  5 22:34:19 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '.' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I have Googled this and all issues I've found are people who are trying to `include()` another file in some way (using other PHP methods). Haven't found anything similar to what I'm experiencing with just a simple echo statement.

NOTE: I've tried giving full read/write/execute permissions to both the `test.php` file and the `test/` directory; same results.

Comment: does anything from this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326531/php-warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream

Comment: here's my php.ini file...; 

`Automatically add files before PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file =

; Automatically add files after PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-append-file
auto_append_file =`

Comment: and your php code is missing a closing tag

Comment: @rccoros ...which is highly recommended

Comment: That I'm not aware of. Can you give me some discussion or page where it is tackled. Thanks Phil!

Comment: @rccoros Sure thing - http://php.net/manual/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ah, don't add the `.`. The built-in server uses the CWD as document root (or the path specified via the `-t` flag). You're attempting to use `.` as a [router script](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-383). Simply run...

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

See http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I'm not sure what changed and when, but i had been calling it with the dot on this same machine for years (i had an alias for it)!  Still, to my amazement, removing the dot did the trick!