# Php error (ambigious)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I've today installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a VMWare machine, it's running PHP7.0.4 and Mysql etc.

However, I get this very ambigious error, which I have no clue how to work around as I am a Linux novice and I was hoping to get some help.

This occurs when loading index.php, I have a file just for phpinfo() that runs just fine;

```
[Mon Jun 20 18:36:12.626797 2016] [:error] [pid 14021] [client 79.136.69.128:56242] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jun 20 18:36:12.626992 2016] [:error] [pid 14021] [client 79.136.69.128:56242] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

The PHP file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/unKfSy0P

I've had the exact same code running on a windows installation of the same PHP verison aswell as on php 5.6 for Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm hopeing for any and all help! Thanks

Comment: It looks like you got file permission problems. What kind of server you run? Apache, NGINX?

Comment: I run apache. I thought it could be that, but I am quite clueless how it works in Ubuntu with permissions. Is there any commands to check for permissions (the server, I think, should be running with root privs, but I might have misunderstood that9

Comment: I think your web server don't have the proper permission for the www/html/ folder.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326531/php-warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream

Comment: You could try changing the read permissions on the `index.php` file using the terminal command: `sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/index.php` (or for all files in the html directory: `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/`)

Comment: Thank you Ben, that did the trick :) (and also to you Romaric, as it was the same but working solution! )