# When installing the codeigniter files in localhost an error is displaying?

Tags: codeigniter

I downloaded a project work and installed it in localhost which is done in codeigniter. But when I installed the files and tried to view the website, it is showing the following error:

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/website/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

I tried many solutions like changed the include_path settings in php.ini and gave the path but still not working. Can anyone suggest a solution for this ? I have changed the database and config settings in the config folder.

Comment: Did you check with proper file permission? check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326531/php-warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create dummy database in mysql server ex:MyExampleDb

then go to application->config->database.php

in there code should like this..change database to MyExampleDb and give username in your mysql server and password that's all..hope this works for you if you need more info contact me can help you via teamviewer

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'MyExampleDb',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: and add the .htaccess